# -[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView keyboardWillHide:]: message sent to deallocated instance in ios?

Tags: ipad

Imported `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.h` and .m files in my xcode projects and used that `TPkeyboard` for my `UIScrollview` in all classes of my project like this

```
 TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView = [[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView alloc] init];
```

The app is terminating and showing the error as

```
-[TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView keyboardWillHide:]: message sent to deallocated
instance.
```

Can anyone please provide me some information.

Thanks in advance.
 `KeyboardWillHide` function in **TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView.m**:

```
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification*)notification {
    _keyboardRect = CGRectZero;
    _keyboardVisible = NO;

    // Restore dimensions to prior size
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue]];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:[[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] floatValue]];

    self.contentInset = _priorInset;
    self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.contentOffset.x, 0);
    [self setScrollIndicatorInsets:self.contentInset];
    _priorInsetSaved = NO;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Try setting `TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView *scrollView` to a strong `@property`.

Comment: I think the TPKeyboardAvoidingScrollView registers for receiving notifications for UIKeyboardWillShowNotification - is it also removed as observer, e.g. when the viewcontroller did disappear? [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];